# Why do i get error error C2664: 'reverseString'

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

typedef char string80[81];      // create a synonym for another type 
void reverseString(string80);       // function prototype 
int main()
{            
  // start program compilation here 
  char string80, name;          // variable to contain the name of the user 

  cout << "Enter your name =====> " ;
  cin >> name,81; 

  cout << "\n\nWelcome to Computer Science 1106 " << name << endl<< endl; 

  reverseString(name);

  cout << "Your name spelled backwards is " << name << endl << endl; 

  return 0;
} // end function main 
  // Function to reverse a string 
  // Pre: A string of size <= 80 Post: String is reversed 

void reverseString(string80 x)
{ 
  int last = strlen(x)- 1;  // location of last character in the string 
  int first = 0;        // location of first character in the string 
  char temp;  

  // need a temporary variable 
  while(first <= last)
  { // continue until last > first 

    temp = x[first];      // Exchange the first and last characters
    x[first] = x[last];         
    x[last] = temp; 
    first++;        // Move on to the next character in the string
    last--;             // Decrement to the next to last character in the string
  }// end while 
}// end reverseString
```

I get an error

> C2664: 'reverseString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to
>   'char []' Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires
>   reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Did you mean `string80 name;` instead of `char string80, name;`? PS you can use `std::string` and `std::reverse` standard functions.

Comment: also `cin >> name,81;` ?

Comment: also, `cin >> name,81;` is fail, you meant `cin >> setw(81) >> name;`

Answer (score 1):

The `reverseString` function accepts `char [81]` for the x parameter yet you are sending it a `char` when you are calling it.

What you probably wanted to do was declare `string80` and `name` as a `char [81]` and not a `char`

```
char string80[81], name[81];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `name` as of type `char`, when it should be typed as `string80` (from your typedef).

You are also accidentally hiding your typedef by declaring `char string80`, which hides the typedef from the surrounding scope.

You want to declare `name` as of type `string80`, not of type `char`. Something like this:

```
string80 name;
```